# Double-spinners on SE mobile app

Tags: bug, android-app

I've noticed 2 loading spinners when performing certain actions on the SE mobile app (Android specifically). One appears to be a modal, the other an element in the page.

Is this intentional? What's the purpose?

Comment: On MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246050/two-loading-sprites-on-android and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252750/two-load-icons-simultaneously-appearing-in-android-app?rq=1

Comment: Good catch, I posted via the app so it didn't recommend related questions.